# How to load my fake module every time when `import a real module` in python?

Tags: python, python-module, python-mock, python-unittest

I need to test on a `function.py`, and in this function.py there is a import statement:

```
from my.functions import cleaner
from my.functions import worker
```

I don't want the `cleaner` get imported because it's very complicated. So I try to set the `sys.path` :

```
sys.path.insert(0, './fakes')
```

in `fakes` module, a `my.functions.cleaner` also exists there but with no function, that works but it will also impact `worker`, I really want the `worker` works for me.

So my question is there any way to "mock" this cleaner to my fake cleaner, I need my fake cleaner replace it every time import cleaner.

I tried `sys.modules` but failed.

Comment: @WernerHenze no, not depends, it's just when `import function` get called, `from my.functions import cleaner` will be get called that I don't want it to.

Comment: OK, I finally find a way for this:

Comment: before all of the codes, use this: `sys.modules['powervc.common.client'] = mock.MagicMock()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to dynamically replace a function, you can do so with an assignment statement, I.E.:

To see this in action check out this example:

import my.functions

`/my`

`functions.py`

```
def cleaner():
    print("Cleaner from functions!")

def worker():
    print("Worker from functions!")
```

`base.py`

```
import my.functions

def cleaner():
    print("Replacement fake cleaner!")

my.functions.cleaner = cleaner


def method_to_test():
    from my.functions import cleaner
    from my.functions import worker
    cleaner()
    worker()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    method_to_test()
```

Python loads the my.functions module into sys.modules, then on subsequent from imports gets objects from the already loaded module, so we can set a mock function before your function does its import.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know I can dynamically replace the methods or attributes to python object, but here is not replace a method or attribute, it's replace a "import ..." statement. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok, I see what you want to do Jerry. Writing something up now.

Comment: thanks for update, but seems you still didn't catch me, here in your my/functions.py, the cleaner and worker is not methods like cleaner() and worker(), it's a import statement. The difference is, if it's a method, it will not be loaded when you `import my.functions`, but if it's a import statement, it will automatically load and execute the class when `import my.functions`. My purpose is to replace the behavior of `import my.functions.cleaner` in function.py, let it not executed when load my.functions. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can write `unittest`s maybe like this:

```
 from mock import MagicMock
 import function

 function.cleaner = MagicMock()

 # test function's methods
```

Comment: when you `import function`, wouldn't `from my.functions import cleaner` get executed?

Comment: Check out my edited response Jerry. It doesn't import the original when you assign something else to the `cleaner` function in `my.functions`.